# TabView ActionBar calling methods for active component

Tags: angular, nativescript

I am working with a TabView using nested routers to load various components. I currently have an ActionBar that dynamically updates its title and visible buttons based on what tab I have open. I am doing this by listening to the `onIndexChanged` event.

### `tabs.component.html`:

```
<ActionBar class="action-bar">
    <Label class="action-bar-title"
        [text]="title"></Label>

    <ActionItem ios.systemIcon="2"
        android.systemIcon="ic_menu_edit"
        visibility="{{ title=='Profile' ? 'visible' : 'collapse' }}"
        [nsRouterLink]="['/tabs', {outlets: {profileoutlet: 'profile/edit'}}]"></ActionItem>

    <ActionItem (tap)="onSave()"
        ios.systemIcon="3"
        android.systemIcon="ic_menu_save"
        ios.position="right"
        visibility="{{ title=='Edit Profile' ? 'visible' : 'collapse' }}" >
        </ActionItem>

    <ActionItem ios.systemIcon="1"
        android.systemIcon="ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"
        visibility="{{ title=='Edit Profile' ? 'visible' : 'collapse' }}"
        [nsRouterLink]="['/tabs', {outlets: {profileoutlet: 'profile'}}]">
        </ActionItem>

</ActionBar>

<TabView androidTabsPosition="bottom"
    (selectedIndexChange)="onIndexChanged($event)">
    <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Profile'}">
        <router-outlet name="profileoutlet"></router-outlet>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Feed'}">
        <router-outlet name="feedoutlet"></router-outlet>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Shop'}">
        <router-outlet name="shopoutlet"></router-outlet>
    </StackLayout>
</TabView>
```

You can see that tapping on the edit profile button will direct one of the tabs to a new page, and will then show the save and cancel buttons.

I would like to be able to click the save button on the action bar, and have it call the save method in the edit-profile component.

I am struggling here because the ActionBar is in the scope of my tabs component, it cannot "see" the edit-profile component, and I don't know how to gain "access" to the edit-profile component to call its methods.

### `tabs.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { TabView, TabViewItem, SelectedIndexChangedEventData } from "ui/tab-view";
import { RouterExtensions } from "nativescript-angular/router";
import { UserService } from "../../services/auth/user.service";

@Component({
    selector: "Tabs",
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "./tabs.component.html"
})
export class TabsComponent implements OnInit {
    title: string;
    RouterExtensions: RouterExtensions;
    UserService: UserService;

    constructor(
        private routerExtensions: RouterExtensions,
        private userService: UserService
    ) {
        this.RouterExtensions = routerExtensions;
        this.UserService = userService;
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
    }

    onIndexChanged(args) {
        let tabView = <TabView>args.object;
        let item: TabViewItem = tabView.items[tabView.selectedIndex];
        this.title = item.title;
    }

    onSave() {
        //somehow call the edit-profile `saveUser()` method from here
    }

    setTitle(title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

I have tried calling `tabView.getViewById()` but I can't actually figure out what the component ID would be and then how i would call methods on that `ViewBase` object.

Comment: Look at the "Parent and children communicate via a service" example in the following link. More particularly, have each routed component subscribe to the same "saveRequested" observable, and trigger that event from the parent component by emitting to the source. Make sure to unsubscribe as shown: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: @arao6 thank you for pointing me in the right direction, I knew there was some solution with an observable / event but could not put my finger on it. Would you like to phrase this as an answer so that I can resolve this question, or are you happy for me to self-answer with the information on that page? In terms of karma I would prefer an external answer but am happy either way